# Resolve CSV Stringify promise within a test or end a test when a function is called?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to mock CSV Stringify with AngularJS...but I just want to grab the two parameters passed in and use them later in the test to test if some options were correct.

```
it("converts latitude and longitude correctly", function() {
  this.CSV._stringifyPromise._setResolveMode("instant");
  var csvFeatures, csvOptions;
  this.CSV.stringify.and.callFake(function(csvFeaturesInStringify,
    csvOptionsInStringify) {
    csvFeatures = csvFeaturesInStringify;
    csvOptions = csvOptionsInStringify;
  });

  this.featureExportCSVService.buildCsvFile(this.features, "Test");
  expect(this.csvOptions[0].LONG).toEqual(this.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
    0].toString());
  expect(this.csvOptions[0].LAT).toEqual(this.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
    1].toString());
});
```

I believe CSV stringify returns a promise in the non-test code as it's called...

```
    CSV.stringify(csvObject.features, csvObject.options)
      .then(function(result) { ... }
```

I assumed it would just be return the result in my call fake but that doesn't seem to work.

```
  this.CSV.stringify.and.callFake(function(csvFeaturesInStringify,
    csvOptionsInStringify) {
    expect(...);
    expect(...);
    return "test,blah,blah";
  });
```

I tried use `$q.defer().resolve();` but `$q` was undefined. Doing a return it just says `undefined is not a constructor`

How would I just resolve this function to just return a dummy String or even just end the test here and evaluate my `expect()` calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to call the return like this with a then function and a successCallback....

```
  this.CSV.stringify.and.callFake(function(csvFeaturesInStringify, csvOptionsInStringify) {
    csvFeatures = csvFeaturesInStringify;
    return {
      then: function(successCallback) {
        successCallback("geometry,LAT,LONG,name,marker-color");
      }
    };
```

Then after the function call that eventually gets to that method, you need to put the expect blocks there not in here.

```
  this.featureExportCSVService.buildCsvFile(this.features, "Test");
  expect(this.csvOptions[0].LONG).toEqual(this.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
    0].toString());
  expect(this.csvOptions[0].LAT).toEqual(this.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
    1].toString());
```